# Error after installing the system

Tags: system-installation, xorg

I had hdd(empty disk) and ssd (with windows 10). After installation, for entry the system elementary OS my PC must be rebooted. And an error occurs(attached photo).
Installation options: on a free space of hdd (about 200gb) I installed: / (about 30gb), swap (about 3gb), /home (all remaining). Bootloader installed on ssd.

[image]